# Convert a Swift Property Observer Into ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, properties

Does this piece of ObjC code have the same result as the Swift?

```
var bottomColor = UIColor.gray {
    didSet {
        self.updateColors()
    }
}
```

vs

```
- (void)setBottomColor:(UIColor *)bottomColor
{
    bottomColor = [[UIColor grayColor];
    if (_bottomColor != bottomColor) {
        _bottomColor = bottomColor;
        [self updateColors];
    }
}
```

If not, how can I correctly translate the Swift?

Comment: Ask yourself: What does each line do and when? See [Objective-C set default value for a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830317/objective-c-set-default-value-for-a-property).

Answer (score 3):

The two codes are not the same.

In Swift, the property observer is called whenever a value is set. It doesn't matter whether the new value is equal to the old value or not. So this code will print "Hello" exactly twice:

```
class A {
    var a: Int = 10 {
        didSet {
            print("Hello")
        }
    }
}

let a = A()
a.a = 10
a.a = 10
```

To convert a property observer to Objective-C, you don't need to check if the value is same as before, just do:

```
- (void)setBottomColor:(UIColor *)bottomColor
{
    _bottomColor = bottomColor;
    [self updateColors];
}
```

`bottomColor` should be set to `[UIColor gray]` in the `init`.

Answer (score 0):

Nope!

In the swift code the bottomColor is a variable that initiate with `gray` and every time it changes (setting another color to it) fires the `updateColors` but in objective-c code the method just fires the `updateColors` if the parameter not equals to `[UIColor grayColor]`

---

**Edit:**

You can implement swift code in objective-c by this way:

• override the setter and implement the setter yourself.
• set the `bottomColor = [UIColor grayColor]` in init.

```
- (void)setBottomColor:(UIColor *)bottomColor
{
    _bottomColor = bottomColor;
    [self updateColors];
}
```

Comment: I want to focus on propery observer